# What SDK-version to use for MT 4.0.3

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

which Apple iOS SDK version do you use for building an MonoTouch 4.0.3 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, they should work from 3.0 up, though you might suffer some limitations if you use the 3.0 IOS SDK.
Currently running with IOS SDK 4.3